# Problems with fgets and strtok in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, fgets, strtok

I need to fill a 2d array with numbers from a string so I am using `strtok` and `fgets` to get the string and tokenize it. However if I enter "1 2 3 4 5" and the 2d array's dimensions are 2x2, the 5 never gets assigned to `number`. I want to check if there are more numbers than the matrix can hold but `number` always ends up being `NULL` after adding the 4 to the matrix instead of 5. I know SIZE is correct because if I print out `stringInputted` before `strtok` it prints out the correct output.

```
scanf("%d", &rows);
scanf("%d", &columns); 
//SIZE = 2*rows*columns+1
//rows and columns are user inputted and stored using scanf
fgets(stringInputted, SIZE, stdin);
 char *number = strtok(stringInputted, " \n");

 for(i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < columns; j++){
        if(number != NULL)
            matrix[i][j] = atoi(number);
        else{
            printf("ERROR Insufficient numbers entered\n");
            return 0;
        }
        number = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
 }
 if(number != NULL) printf("TOO MANY NUMBERS\n");
```

Comment: Could you include your definitions of `SIZE`, `rows`, and `columns`? Also, your question mentions `input` but your code lists `stringInputted`.

Comment: Edited. @chrisaycock

Comment: Cannot reproduce when wrapped in a `main` function. For a 2x2 matrix 3 values give "ERROR insufficent..." and 5 values give "TOO MANY NUMBERS" and with 4 values it stays quiet.

Comment: Hmm thats strange, How are you inputting the values? I have it so the user inputs them in 1 string "2 2 1 2 3 4..." The first two would be the size of the matrix. @WeatherVane

Comment: length of `1 2 3 4 5` is `9`. So `SIZE`  needs 10 or more.

Comment: I input the values from a redirected text file containing the 5 values you show. Why would the 5th value `5` ever be assigned to `number` when the loop is 2 * 2 nested iterations? BTW my input string was a generous `char stringInputted[100];` (before you posted the `SIZE` calculation). Never be mean with your string space unless you are in a very limited environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SIZE` is incorrect.

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream... A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So you need to consume 10 bytes, not nine.

Comment: How would I allocate SIZE if I do not know how many numbers the user will input? Like if they want a 2x2 matrix but they input 10 numbers (so 20 characters including spaces)

Comment: @TirthRami And this is the trouble with reading user strings in C. Other languages automatically grow the buffer. In C, you'll have to use dynamic memory allocation and `realloc()` the array if you notice more input available. This is a complicated topic and far beyond the scope of a single comment.

Comment: @TirthRami why would you need to read numbers that you cannot process? If there can be 12 characters in a signed `int` including the space, the maximum string length will be `rows * columns * 12 + 2` (newline and nul). Add another `12` so that you can know if too many numbers were input.